# Galaxy Note 4 screen problem?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-4

Recently I got a note 4 and when i turn on the screen, it has these orange faded pictures, and i'm guessing the last owner played candy crush while burning the phone?

Does it have a reset option? Or do I have to replace the LCD or the screen?

EDIT: Added screenshot requested by Rahul Gopi:

[image]

Look very closely to the screen, not my bedsheets XD

Comment: a screen shot will be helpful

Comment: adding soon ^ :D

Comment: @RahulGopi added, please check

Comment: please check in settings > developer option, whether simulate color space is disabled. disabled is default RGB mode.or check settings> display> live display , display mode, color calibration, color temperature. ( I am on Lineage os, nougat 7.1.2)